# Where do I put my interface in the following function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, typescript-typings, react-typescript

This is my Interface that I want to put in the props, but I dont know where to put it.

```
interface LinkTabProps {
    label: string;
    href: string;
};
```

This is the function. I assume it should be put somehwere around (props: { label, href }). But I cant figure out where.

```
const LinkTab = (props: { label, href }) => (
  <Tab
    component="a"
    onClick={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
    /* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
    {...props}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick(if it doesnt declare LinkTabProps as class):

```
const LinkTab = (props: LinkTabProps) => (
  <Tab
    component="a"
    onClick={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
    /* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
    {...props}
  />
);
```

Comment: I marked it as the answer but can't upvote it since I dont have 15 reputations :) hope it helps